# Make a "multiline" recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So, normally, a `RecyclerView` is either horizontal or vertical like below diagram:

[image]

I have no problem producing both of above. But now, I want to make a `RecyclerView` which is "multi-line"-ey (I don't know if this is a correct way to name it). Basically, like in notepad, if you check "Wrap Text", then the off-screen texts will be sent to the next line.

So the behavior is like `HorizontalRecyclerView` but the items will fill horizontally first before going below.

Assuming each size of the child items is identical, it'll be a good thing too to make it centered on the screen.

**Similar like:**

[image]

**But not like (It's not centered on the screen):**

[image]

Btw, I somehow prefer my collections to be managed by `RecyclerView` rather than `TableLayout`, since I never used `TableLayout` before, and `RecyclerView` seems the most efficient to reuse a layout of a collections.

Comment: do you want items of recyclerView to be shown in grid-type of layout? then @Ravi 's answers is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set `GridLayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`

```
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns));
```

Reference : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579811/changing-number-of-columns-with-gridlayoutmanager-and-recyclerview)

Comment: Is there some way to dynamically set the number of columns? Just like both Vertical and Horizontal `RecyclerView` that dynamically "adjust" to screen size.

Comment: In that case you can find screen size and perform your own logic whatever you needed. For example If your cell size is 200 and screen size is 800 you can have 3 or 4 columns

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 possible ways by which you can arrange your RecyclerView layout.

- LinearLayoutManger – for traditional lists [Look here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html)
- GridLayoutManager – for table view [Look here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)
- StaggeredGridLayoutManager - staggered grid formation [Look here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)

[[LinearLayout Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En2dP.jpg)

[[Grid Layout Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkF4g.jpg)

[[Staggered Grid Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngjU3.jpg)

For your question, you can use `GridLayoutManager` as @Ravi answered

```
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns));
```

For dynamically change number of columns, you can refer [this link](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-autofit-grid.html)